# Understanding the general theory proposed by Neyman & Pearson

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, references, history, neyman-pearson-lemma

I'm reading [Neyman & Pearson, 1933](http://www.joelvelasco.net/teaching/249/Neyman%20Pearson%201933.pdf), i.e.

> Neyman and Pearson. On the problem of the most efficient tests of statistical hypotheses. Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London. Series A, Containing Papers of a Mathematical or Physical Character (1933) vol. 231 pp. 289-337

(Sorry for taking a screenshot, but there is too much typing, and the diagram on the original paper must be included anyway)

[image]

Here are my two quick questions:

1. What is "the ordinary method of Calculus of Variations"? It looks like Lagrange multiplier, but the position of the constant $k$ is strange.
2. Why does $\omega_0(\alpha)$ must "lie entirely inside the region $\omega_0$"? In the diagram, the shaded areas pointed out by the arrows clearly fall out of $\omega_0$, which is limited by $S$.

Comment: For question 1, indeed it is the Lagrange multiplier. The Neyman-Pearson problems is a linear program with convex constraints. Passing to the dual formulation gives the dual variable/Lagrange multiplier. "Calculus of variation" is really old school terminology and would not be proper today.